# Switching Between Root and Non-Root Users in Docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes

So I'm trying to deploy a Django app on Minikube. But in one of the containers, the image requires me to be in `root` for certain tasks and then switch the `postgres` user to create some databases and then switch back to `root` to run more commands.

I know I can use the `USER` functionality for Docker but that messes up certain task depending on what user I'm in. I have also tried running `su - postgres` but that returns an error saying that the command has to be from the terminal.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Way short on necessary information, but in short -- this isn't a docker thing.   It's an OS thing.    You can flip users in shell scripts just like normal.   Or, do the one container per process thing and split out postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical tool for this in is [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu). When included in your container, you'd run `gosu postgres $cmd` where the command is whatever you need to run. If it's the only command you need to have running in the container at the end of your entrypoint script, then you'd `exec gosu postgres $cmd`. The gosu page includes details of why you'd use their tool, the main reasons being TTY and signal handling. Note the end of their readme also lists a few other alternatives which are worth considering.

Comment: Would I run `gosu` in my `entrypoint.sh` or would i run it in my Dockerfile?

Comment: Nevermind, I looked over the docs a bit more, this is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If say container is based on the official [Postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/), you can try create a script for all your `root` tasks and `COPY` that script to the container's `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder. Any `.sql` and `.sh` scripts in this folder will be executed **AFTER** the entrypoint calls `initdb`, with `gosu postgres` as seen in the [entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/a00e979002aaa80840d58a5f8cc541342e06788f/9.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L42-L111).

If you need to sandwich the `initdb` between two sets of `root` tasks, then you will have to carve your own entrypoint script.